# Matrix operation repeat matrix members

Tags: matrices, computational-complexity, tensor-products, tensors

I am going to use `C++ Armadillo` library which handles matrices to generate matrix $B$ and $C$ from matrix $A$.

$$
A=[M_0,M_1,\ldots,M_{n-1}]^T
$$

$$
B=[M_0,M_0,M_0,M_1,M_1,M_1,\ldots,M_{n-1},M_{n-1},M_{n-1}]^T
$$

$$
C=[-M_0,0,+M_0,-M_1,0,+M_1,,\ldots,-M_{n-1},0,+M_{n-1}]^T
$$

One possible way is to use a for loop doing that. But since for loop is slower than simple matrix operations involving graphic card processing, I was thinking if there is any simple matrix operation which can build matrix B and C.

Since $A$ is $(n-1)\times1$ while $B$ and $C$ are $3(n-1)\times1$, it is not possible to obtain B and C through a simple matrix multiplication like:
$$B=D\times A, C=E\times A$$

I am not sure about tensors. Is there any GPU friendly operation for it?

Comment: Since $B,C$ have such rich structure, are you sure you really want to generate them?  Whatever you do with them you can probably do with just $A$ and some care.

Comment: I need to calculate G=B+(1/6)C-(1/6)(C shifted 3 rows). This process occurs so many times in a loop.

Comment: You really have three different $G$'s, one where $G_i=(5M_i-M_{i+1})/6$, one whee $G_i=M_i$, and one where $G_i=(7M_i+M_{i+1})/6$.